# Member Object Calling Class Method

Tags: java, oop, interface

I hope this question is not really a repetition of an existing one! I searched and found no good answer to my question. Here it is:

I have a class MyGame that contains a Button member object. Whenever that button is clicked, MyGame should do something.

```
class MyGame extends Application {
    MyBoard board = new MyBoard();
    MyButton btn = new MyButton();

    public MyGame() {
        board.add(btn);
    }

    // this method should be called whenever the button is clicked!
    public void doSomething() {
        doingSomething();
    }
}

class MyButton extends Button {
    int someData;

    // some code here

    public MyButton() {
        this.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                MyGame.doSomething();  // ==> NOT POSSIBLE!!!
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Would an interface be the best way to make the communication between the MyButton and MyGame go? If so, how would you do it?

I don't want to hand over a reference of MyGame object to the MyButton object! I think this is not a good way to resolve this problem.

I appreciate any suggestions and help!

Cheers

Comment: If you take a look at the [Button class in the java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html), you will see that there is a function named addActionListener. A quick search on how to use it on google should give you plenty of information to go on from there!

Answer (score 3):

In the constructor of `MyGame` you can add an `ActionListener` to `btn` that will be called when an action is performed on the button.

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Insert thing to do within MyGame here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to do it the other way around (game should be a member of button). I know that you think "it is not a good way to resolve this problem", but you think wrong, there is really nothing wrong with it.

Alternatively, move the registering of the listener out of the button's constructor into the game itself:

```
public MyGame() {
   btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
       public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) { doSomething(); }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the interesting idea. I will possibly reconsider my program. Sometimes it is a matter of rethinking to get things done :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make the "button action" an interface that can be passed to the constructor when creating `MyButton`.  Example:

```
public MyButton(final Runnable action) {
    this.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            action.run();  // POSSIBLE!!!
        }
    });
}
```

or save the action in a `MyButton` instance field:

```
public MyButton(Runnable action) {
    buttonAction = action;     // make buttonAction an instance field
    this.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            buttonAction.run(); 
        }
    });
}
```

Then when `MyGame` creates a new `MyButton`, the `MyGame` gets to tell the button what to do when the button is clicked:

```
MyButton btn = new MyButton(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MyGame.this.doSomething();
    }
}
```

or in Java 8:

```
MyButton btn = new MyButton(this::doSomething);
```

**NOTE:** I haven't yet tested this.  I think I got the syntax right, but I may have made a mistake.  You may need to assign `btn` in the `MyGame` constructor rather than in an initializer expression.

This is a generalized approach (dependency injection?) that works in lots of situations.  There may be other solutions specific to `Button` (or other Swing components for which a listener mechanism is already defined).  But this mechanism reduces coupling, because the `MyButton` doesn't really need to know anything about who created it, and the `MyGame` doesn't need to know what the `MyButton` plans to do with the `Runnable` action.  Some other possible solutions involve having `MyGame` doing some of `MyButton`'s work, which increases coupling.

Comment: What does "this" represent here in the new MyButton(new Runnable) anonymous class?

Comment: @dragon66 It should have been `MyGame.this`--thanks for catching this.  I still haven't tested my code.  (I suspect the `MyGame.this` isn't really necessary, and it would find `doSomething()` in the outer class anyway.)

Comment: This answer is really excessive. You don't need that much complexity.. Look at Oli's answer, much simpler.

Comment: @Crembo That solution potentially increases coupling, which increases the chance that when a maintainer tries to modify one class in the future they will inadvertently break another class.  The answer you cite makes the `MyGame` class do part of the `MyButton` job.  That's something that should be avoided in well-designed software.

Comment: Or you know, if you want to reduce coupling you can just create a named class instead of an annonymous one and that's it. Still the solution is much simpler than yours.

Comment: @ajb: Thank you so much for the good answer. I learned a lot!!